# Kotlin spring JPA. lateinit property has not been initialized exception from getting lazy field of JPA entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I use Spring Boot, Hibernate, Kotlin

In build.gradle.kts:

```
apply(plugin="org.hibernate.orm")

tasks.withType<org.hibernate.orm.tooling.gradle.EnhanceTask>().configureEach {
    options.enableLazyInitialization = true
    options.enableDirtyTracking = true
    options.enableAssociationManagement = true
}
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    class User(
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "id")
            var id: Long = -1,    
    
            @Column(name = "user_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
            var userName: String = "",
    
    
            @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
            var email: String = "",

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")], 
             inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id")])
             var roles: MutableSet<Role> = mutableSetOf()
    
    
    ) {
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "user", optional = false)
        @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
        @LazyGroup( "person" )
        lateinit var person: Person
    ....
    
    }
```

I get it by:

```
@Transactional
@Component
class UserServiceImpl (private val userRepository: UserRepository){

    
    override fun getUserData(id: Long): Optional<UserView> {
      return  userRepository.findById(id).map { UserView.build(it, it.person) }

    }
...

}
```

And it.person throws `lateinit property has not been initialized exception`, but Person was loaded( I see it by hibernate log ). Getting roles works fine.

I have same result without  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY) and  @LazyGroup( "person" ).

---

SOLVED:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
    @LazyGroup( "person" )
   lateinit var person: Person
```

Comment: lateinit should be initialized before accessing it

Comment: It is obvious that hibernate does not initialize field, although the data is retrieved. How to do one-to-one with fetch = FetchType.LAZY without lateinit var or with it to work?  I don`t wont to use nullable var.

Comment: I changed User entity to use  var person: Person?, but but person is not set by Hibernate

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: See original question